# Did Isaac Barrow also discover the other thing about inverse relation between area and tangent?

Tags: math-history

Barrow surely discovered that the tangent to the area curve of a function at a point equals the value of the function at that point. Also, I’ve seen geometric proofs of this.

But did he also discover that the area function of the tangent function (or derivative, in modern terms) of a function at a point also evaluated to the function value at that point plus some constant for all the points in the domain?

Comment: I suggest that you pot this question [here](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos okay, done.